# IF statement not working as expected in Tkinter

Tags: python, if-statement, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

I am using Tkinter to build a simple calculator. I want to make sure that if a new number is pressed after an answer was displayed, the number doesn't get concatenated with the previous answer. I have cast only the answer variable as a float so that it can be unique and I can check its object class. I did this by using an IF statement in line 11. However, it appears the IF statement isn't working as expected... Please what do you suggest?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")
form1 = Entry(root, width=34, borderwidth=5)
form1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

#what happens when a number is clicked
def btn_click(number):
    current = form1.get()
    form1.delete(0, END)
    if not isinstance(current, float): #check if the previous number is not an answer
        form1.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))

def btn_clear(): #the clear button
    form1.delete(0, END)

def btn_add():#addition button
    first_num = form1.get()
    global f_num
    f_num = int(first_num)
    form1.delete(0, END)


def btn_equal(): #equal button
    second_num = form1.get()
    second_num = int(second_num)
    form1.delete(0, END)
    answer = f_num + second_num
    answer =float(answer)
    form1.insert(0, answer)
```

Sample button codes::

```
btn0 =Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command= lambda: btn_click(0))

btn1 =Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: btn_click(1))
btn2 =Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: btn_click(2))
```

Comment: `Entry.get` probably is returning a string, so you need to test if you get an empty string, not if it's of type `float`: `if current == "": . . .`.

Comment: `.get()` on an entry will always return a string.

Comment: Sure @MuhammedAboo_Anas, no problem.